# How fast did the Aniara travel?

Tags: movie, aniara

In the final chapter of the film *Aniara*, she was

> arriving at an earth-like planet in the constellation Lyra.

Captain Chefone announced their cruising speed would be 64 km/s.

Assuming this was the closest star in Lyra, how fast did she actually travel?

*(Please use spoiler notation in your answers!)*

Comment: Don't forget to use the Movie tag to show that you're wanting answers about the film, not the poem (although I suspect a good answer about this film might end up drawing on both)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should be (in theory) quite easy to work out. We know from the [final panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNbFl.png) that the Aniara traveled for 5,981,407 years before reaching its destination. We also know that its destination was the Constellation Lyra. Unfortunately, this is where the calculations break down a bit since Lyra isn't a *place*, but rather a cluster of stars that happen to be in the same direction when viewed from Earth, but sitting at dramatically different distances.

Assuming the ship hit a planet at [Vega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega) (the brightest and closest star in that constellation, 25 light years from Earth) the ship would have traveled at approximately (approx) **0.000004c** (25.05 / 5,981,407), or approximately 1.25km/s.

Assuming the ship hit a planet at [Gamma Lyrae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_Lyrae) (the farthest visible star in the classic Lyran constellation, 620 light years from Earth), the ship would have needed to be traveling at (approx) **0.0001c** (619.7 / 5,981,407) or about 31km/s.

This, of course, doesn't remove the possibility that they traveled *through Lyra and out the other side* and hit something that was merely in the same direction.

Comment: hat tip to DavidW, who I suspect from his comments wouldn't be happy sharing a car journey with me, for correcting my speed calculations.

Comment: Corrected the magnitude of the first number (it was off by 10), you can delete where I showed my work. :)  I have no idea how to deal with it, but the time scale (6My) is long enough that most of the stars will have moved a _lot_ in that time.  Vega, for instance, will be 12ly closer to the Sun in just 250,000 years!

Comment: @DavidW - That seems to be something the film doesn't address in any detail. They're traveling toward a non-fixed point in space at an indeterminate speed. I think we've done reasonably well to narrow it down as far as we have.

Comment: She was actually crawling along. Our fastest real ship today [travels 192 km/s](https://www.space.com/41447-parker-solar-probe-fastest-spacecraft-ever.html) and could have reached Vega within 39,000 years - short enough to sustain basic microorganisms through the flight.